# Schur polynomials are polynomials but also sequences on a lattice?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-combinatorics, root-systems, characters

Monomial symmetric polynomials in $n$ variables $x_1, \ldots x_n$ form a natural basis for the space $\mathcal{S}_n$ of symmetric polynomials in $n$ variables and are defined by additive symmetrization of the function $x^{\lambda} = x_1^{\lambda_1} x_2^{\lambda_2} \ldots x_n^{\lambda_n}$. Here $\lambda$ is a sequence of $n$ nonnegative numbers, arranged in non-increasing order.(i.e a partition of some integer with number of parts $l(\lambda) \le n$)

Power sum polynomials $p_\lambda$ on $n$ variables also form a basis for $\mathcal{S}_n$

and are defined as
$p_\lambda = \prod_{i=1}^n p_{\lambda_i}$, where $p_r = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^r$.

Schur functions $s_\lambda$ (polynomials), indexed by partitions $\lambda$ of at most $n$ parts, form a basis of the space of symmetric polynomials, are characterized uniquely by two properties:

1. $\langle s_\lambda, s_\mu \rangle = 0$ when $\lambda \neq \mu$, where the inner product is defined on the power sum basis by $\langle p_\lambda, p_\mu \rangle = \delta_{\lambda,\mu} z_\lambda$, and $z_\lambda = \prod_{i=1}^n i^{\alpha_i} \alpha_i !$, where $\alpha_i$ is the number of parts in $\lambda$ whose lengths all equal $i$. Notice $n!/z_\lambda$ is the size of the conjugacy class in the symmetric group $S_{\sum \lambda_i}$ whose cycle structure is given precisely by $\lambda$.
2. If one writes $s_\lambda$ as linear combination of $m_\mu$'s, then the $m_\lambda$ coefficient is $1$ and $m_\mu$ coefficients are all $0$ if $\mu > \lambda$, meaning the partial sums inequality $\sum_{i=1}^k \mu_i \ge \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i$ hold for all $k$ and is strict for at least one $k$. Thus one can say the transition matrix from Schur to monomial polynomial basis is upper triangular with $1$'s on the diagonal.

Schur polynomials are connected to root systems. More specifically, given a root system, one can view a Schur polynomial, not just as a polynomial as described above, but as a function (sequence) defined on the weight lattice of a root system. So each Schur polynomial $s_{\lambda} \mapsto \sum_{\mu \in I}c_{\lambda}e^{\mu}$ where $\mu$ is a lattice point in the weight lattice.

It's not difficult to find a paper/textbook talking about Schur polynomials that assumes one of these two perspectives on Schur polynomials. However, what I cannot seem to find in any textbook/paper I've seen is the following:

How do you make this transition from a polynomial $s_{\lambda} \in \mathcal{S_n}$ to a sequence on a weight lattice. That is given a Schur polynomial, as an actual polynomial, how do I turn it into a sequence on a weight lattice? Or vice cersa?

Comment: Your notation $s_{\lambda} \mapsto \sum_{\lambda \in I} c_{\lambda}e^{\lambda}$ is a bit confusing because you use $\lambda$ on both sides for different things, but anyways the coefficient of a weight $\mu$ when viewing $s_{\lambda}$ as a "sequence" on the weight lattice should just be the coefficient of $x^{\mu}$ in the expansion of $s_{\lambda}$ into monomials. This is the same as the dimension of the $\mu$-weight space in the irreducible representation $V^{\lambda}$ of the general linear group.

Comment: Thank you. I was not careful enough. However, I don't understand what is $x^{\mu} $ is when $ \mu$ is a point in the weight lattice.

Comment: It's exactly the same as your $x^{\lambda}$: the weight lattice of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ is just $\mathbb{Z}^n$. (For $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ there is an annoying issue where we have to mod out by $\langle (1,1,\ldots,1)\rangle$, but that doesn't affect much.)

Comment: I still don't understand. Even in the simple case of $\mathbb{Z}^n$, we how do you interpret $x^{\mu} $ when $ \mu$ has a negative component. As you have written, $x^{\mu} $ would not be a polynomial. Moreover, for other lattices, e.g those gotten from the $A_n$ root system, I especially don't understand. Are you saying we should identify the lattice with $\mathbb{Z}^n$ ?

Comment: The $\mu$ won't have negative components because if $\lambda$ is a partition then the $\mu$-weight spaces of $V^{\lambda}$ with nonzero mulitiplicty are only for $\mu$ with nonnegative entries (the negatives come from inverse powers of the determinant, and again don't matter much; alternatively, you can work with $\mathfrak{sl}_n$). For root systems other than Type A things are different, but then we have something else in the place of the Schur polynomials: e.g. orthogonal characters or symplectic characters, etc.